# How can I replace image inside a TD with loading image during Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, image

I have an HTML table. In each cell there is an image followed by some text. Something like this:

```
<td>
  <img src='image.gif'>This is a test
</td>
```

I have to run a jQuery Ajax call and during this call I want to change the image to a loading image that I have (loading.gif) and then return it to the regular image (image.gif in this case) after the Ajax is complete.

What is the correct jQuery syntax to change the image to the loading image and back again?

Comment: What is your question about? How to address the image, or how to change the image source?

Comment: @Pekka - updated question to be more explicit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your question is regarding how to change an image before an AJAX Request and then change it back when the AJAX request is finished.

Well below is a sample...and here is some reference to the [jQuery ajax() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Note: the ajax() method contains options to declare success, error and complete function that can be executed when the AJAX call is successful, errors out, or is completed (ie after either success or error).

```
<td>
  <img id="loadingImg" src='image.gif'>This is a test
</td>
```

---

```
$("#loadingImg").attr("src", "loading.gif");
$.ajax({ //other options here
  complete: function () {
  $("#loadingImg").attr("src", "image.gif");  // change image back when ajax request is complete
} });
```

Answer (score 3):

To change the image is relatively easy:

```
$('img[src="image.gif"]').attr('src','path/to/new/image.png');
```

The selector could be improved if your image had an `id` (`$('#imageIDname')`, which would apply only to that *one* image element) or `class` (`$('.imageClassName')` though that would apply to *all* images of that class-name). I don't know if you want to apply this to *all* images in all `td`s or just to one particular `img` element.

Coupling that to your ajax call is a little trickier, since I have no idea what your ajax call looks like.

Also, and this might be just my obsessiveness, your element should look like:

```
<img src='image.gif' />This is a test
```

Note the trailing `/` in the `img` tag.

Comment: +1 but I would really use an unique ID, not the image source, as the selector

Comment: @Pekka, absolutely, see my edit regarding use of `id` or `class` (obviously `id` is far better, but I have no idea if he wants to apply this to **all** images on the page or not, since he notes that *each cell has an image*).

Comment: closing the image tag is completely dependent on the DOC Type.

Comment: @John: I *know* but...it just *looks* **messy** when an empty element's not closed properly. That's why I said it 'might be just my obsessiveness.' And since he didn't tell us anything about his page, beyond that one snippet, it seemed worthwhile pointing it out.

Comment: good point about the OP having an image in each cell! Didn't catch that.