# How to show preload image during loading page and also how to show in middle of dynamic conent in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have popup modalbox Iframe which can be open by onclick function using jquery. It's open fine. And in Iframe popup dynamic content is displayed. But it takes some time. I want to put preload image until content of Iframe is displayed. For example:

```
   $('#preloadingImgDiv').fadeIn('slow', function() {});
   url ='something.php?somethingname='+somethingname+'&somethingid='+somethingid;
   $("#iframeId").attr('src',url);
   $('#preloadingImgDiv').fadeOut('slow', function(){});
```

It works. But before coming dynamic content in Iframe popup box, preload image are disappeared.I need preload image is displayed continuously until dynamic content of Iframe popup Modalbox has been come. And another thing, this preload image is needed to display in the middle of content of Iframe popup Modal box.I have design like that
div html, Iframe, dynamic content coming in php.  how to fix it.
I need your hand
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i get your question clearly but i think you want to display your loading image untill content is fully loaded. You are calling `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` at the same time so it becomes visible and invisible before your ajax(or any other) request completed, but you need to call `.fadeIn` when your loading request started and `.fadeOut` when it's completed.

Here is a question and answer like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4240660/1241723

Comment: How to put preload image in Iframe popup modal box.I have shown the content of Iframe like url ='something.php?somename='+somename+'&someid='+someid;
  $("#socialprofilemymodal").attr('src',url);
Here when I use $.ajax({  }), It cann't open Iframe popup modalbox.